# Automator service, bash script: get folder files

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, automator

I have this working Automator/bash script, which watermarks all files which I select:

```
watermark=~/Dropbox/watermark.png
shopt -s nocasematch
for f; do
  [[ $f =~ .*\.(jpe?g|png)$ ]] || continue
  d="${f%/*}/wm_$(date +%Y_%m_%d)"
  mkdir -p "$d"
  target="$d/${f##*/}"
  size=$(/usr/local/bin/identify -format '%[fx:w/4,279]' "$f")
  /usr/local/bin/composite -dissolve 10% -gravity SouthEast\
  \( $watermark -geometry $size \) "$f" -quality 100 "$target"
done
```

[image: automator]
The problem with this setup, that does not work If I select folder (of course in this case I set type to Files and folders in Automator) with images inside (works only if I select images).

My second question is, how to modify this code to make selectedfolder_watermarked folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script only works with folders and it saves for example `~/Desktop/dir1/file1.png` to `~/Desktop/dir1_watermarked/file1.png`:

```
watermark=~/Dropbox/watermark.png
shopt -s nocasematch extglob
for dir; do
  mkdir "$dir"_watermarked
  for f in "$dir"/*.@(png|jpg|jpeg); do
    size=$(/usr/local/bin/identify -format '%[fx:w/4,279]' "$f")
    /usr/local/bin/composite -dissolve 10% -gravity SouthEast \
    \( $watermark -geometry $size \) "$f" -quality 100 "$dir"_watermarked/"${f##*/}"
  done
done
```